# Issue with SonarQube QualityGate on failed commit

Tags: c#, tfs, sonarqube

I'm having an issue with the QualityGate feature of SonarQube.
We've set our QualityGate up so it checks on newly added warnings/errors since the last successful commit. This works great, but not as I'd expected.
Since we've added SonarQube during the development proces we have a legacy of issues.

Given the next situation:
Baseline: The last successful commit has 100 remaining issues. (passed the Quality Gate)
Dev #1 works on the baseline and has fixed the first 20 issues, but introduced new issues (Checkin failed).
Dev #2 also works on the baseline and has fixed the next 20 issues and didn't introduced new issues. The changes made by Dev #1 aren't available to Dev #2.

What I'd expect is that the commit of Dev #2 would be successful. But his checkin also fails. The reason is 20 newly introduced issues. The exact same issues Dev #1 had fixed in his failed commit.

Any idea's how to fix this issue?

Extra info:
SonarQube version: 6.5
We use TFS to check the QualityGate

EDIT:
The meaning of check-in failed is that the QualityGate blocks the newly added code based on newly added issues (since the Leak period)

EDIT2:
With "100 remaining issues" I'm referring to the "Bugs & Vulnerabilities", "Code Smells" and "Duplications".

Comment: Please [edit] your question to elaborate on what it means for the "checkin" to "fail"

Comment: The meaning of check-in failed is that the QualityGate blocks the newly added code based on newly added issues (since the Leak period)

Comment: And when you say "last successful commit has 100 remaining issues" you mean that the commit passed the quality gate? It would be helpful to to [edit] your question to include the criterion on which the subsequent commits are failing the Quality Gate.

Comment: Yes, the "The last successful commit has 100 remaining issues." means that check-in passed the Quality Gate and that the Leak Period is set to this check-in.
With "100 remaining issues" I'm referring to the "Bugs & Vulnerabilities", "Code Smells" and "Duplications".

Comment: To be clear, Dev #2's commit includes the issues introduced by Dev #1?

Comment: Both Dev #1 and Dev #2 are working on the code from "The last successful commit". The changes made by Dev #1 aren't available by Dev #2

Comment: Has Dev #2 fixed 20 issues in the same files that Dev #1 had fixed?

Comment: No, he hasn't. The modified files are completely different.

Comment: @Jownster Have you tired to merge the Dev #1 and Dev #2? Then try to commit again.

Comment: Merging code is a no-go, this would mean that the whole team needs to merge code with each other and then one has to commit. This is going to cost a lot of time.

Comment: You can try to commit Dev #2 to a new branch, then merge the branch.

Comment: Like I said, merging code (if it is in one branch or in multiple) is a no-go.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam Could you help me with this issue?